# Local LAMP Stack on Linux Mint theme upload fails

Tags: themes

I am quite some Linux noob so please bear with me.

I installed a LAMP stack and adjusted upload_size in the php.ini so i can finally install a theme. so far so good.

yet when i try to install it, i am asked to log into a FTP-Server.

It is a local installation so why does it ask me to log into the ftp?

I remember having installed themes and there was no such login-problem before.

Does anybody have an idea?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

the apache server didn't have rights to access the folders it seems. i made it owner over the wordpress folder by issueing following command:

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/wordpress

and now it works.